# Auto Mount virtiofs

Tags: mount, 22.04, fstab

So I have a KVM of Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS running on my Server. The base operating system is Open Media Vault 6 (Debian-based). I have 2 file systems I am passing through to the KVM, I can mount them using this in the terminal:

```
sudo mount -t virtiofs D3 /home/warcraft/Videos/D3 
sudo mount -t virtiofs D5 /home/warcraft/Videos/D5
```

I have searched for various guides and cannot find a way to add this mounting process to `fstab` to have them automatically mounted. Any guidance would be appreciated. I have tried the basic

`D3 /home/warcraft/Video/D3 virtiofs rw 0 0` and get errors:

```
mount: /home/warcraft/Video/D3: mount point does not exist
```

Comment: In your manual mount the path is /home/warcraft/Videos/D3 , in your fstab example it's /home/warcraft/Video/D3  ... Videos and Video is not the same, are they both supposed to exist, or is the fstab a spelling error ?

Comment: Cannot believe I missed that... so embarrassed lol thank you